Springboot MongoDb, collection with two values as compound unique
I am running a Springboot3 with MongoDb where I cannot figure out how to set up a collection which has two fields which in compination must be unique.
There is not effect if not having set a unique compound index on the collection.
I would have thought that declaring it on the Java-Entity would be sufficient.
Some code:
@Document("Asset")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(def = "{'userId': 1, 'name': 1}", unique = true)
})
public class Asset {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    ...


The fields userId and name must be unique within the collection.
That does not have any effect. I do have an @EnableMongoRepositories on my MongoConfiguration:
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@Slf4j
public class MongoConfiguration {

    private final String mongoDatabaseName = "testNoSql";
    private final String mongoDatabaseAddress = "localhost:27017";


On the other hand I am using MongoDb Compass to see on the database part what's going on.
In the collection Asset I would expect to have an extra index declared which is not the case. I create one manually:
The effect is that it does not act like a compound key but rather as a simple field unqiue key. An entry with a userId may only exist once, no matter what the name will be set on.

I would have expected so far by reading docs and hints that the @EnableMongoRepositories would provide building the compound key on the database side automatically (like @Id does).
All examples I have seen seem to work out of the box but for me it seems that they are hiding some settings.
Anyone there could enlighten me? Thank you in advance.

Was there already data in the collection?  If there are any duplicates, building a unique index would fail.

You can create another class for id and userId. Adding that class as an object in your Asset class and put an annotation @id for that object.
Reff: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-composite-key
